# Jquery: Passing Variable (Get)

Tags: jquery

I need to pass the variable category as GET, that is, i want in the url ?category=category but i don't know why it doesn't appear!

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar li").click(function(e) {
        var category = $(this).html();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/',
            data: {
                category: category
            },
            success: function(data) {}
        });
    });
});​
```

Thanks

EDIT: I need to pass the variable in the same page where I am: index.php

Comment: so the url is just www.domain.com/?category=sdgsd?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? display the results somewhere? what backend code accepts your get request?

Comment: What are you seeing in the console? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Isn't POST the method that puts it in the URL?  Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @kevin628 GET is the one that puts it after a ? in the url

Comment: @Sam Ah, thanks. I always get the two confused.

Comment: What do you see in firebug? a POST request? how the URL looks like?

Comment: What's the error ? The page is being loaded on ajax success ?

Answer (score 0):

what should appear where ? you make the get request, but dont do anything with the return. (which is ok in some cases)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#sidebar li").click(function(e) {
        var category = $(this).html();
        $.get('/?category='+category, function(data){
             alert('Return was: '+data);
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I tryed your code but it just shows me the alert with the entire html page as message and then nothing! :( (no ?category etc. in the url)

Comment: @CarloMelisi You have to do something with the data.

Comment: i think, you dont want ajax, what you want in your click event is:
`window.location.href = '/?category='+category;` instead of the `$.get();`

Answer (score 0):

use any debug tool like firebug or other to look at the requests you will see the request being sent by your page and why are you sending it to just / . Are you trying to post it to the same page that would make no sense. Otherwise try making one another file and accepting the get request from there.